# Trigger parent observable subscribe

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have observable variable:

```
var mouse = ko.observable({
    x: ko.observable(),
    y: ko.observable()
});
```

I want subscribe event of `mouse` to be called when either `x` or `y` changes:

```
mouse.subscribe(function(){
    alert('changed');
});

mouse().x(5);
mouse().y(7);
```

But it does not. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Can you provide some more context as to what you're trying to solve?  It sounds like a computed observable may simplify things for you, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: @PatrickSteele In real case I want to find out if mouse was moved (x, or y changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this:

```
mouse().x.subscribe(function () { mouse.valueHasMutated() });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/x9MWp/

Or even better:

```
for (var prop in mouse()) {
    if (ko.isObservable(mouse()[prop])) mouse()[prop].subscribe(function () { mouse.valueHasMutated() });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/x9MWp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed observable that is a function of both x and y:

```
self.mousePos = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.x() + self.y();
});
```

Then subscribe to `mousePos`.

Comment: will it trigger if `{ x: 5, y: 6 }` changes to `{ x: 6, y: 5 }`?

Comment: No, you're correct, it won't.  I originally had a more complex formula to account for stuff like that (as well as making sure X and Y values of zero aren't used in a multiplication formula), but I figured those are issues you can iron out based on testing.  Will someone really be able to move the mouse exactly one and only pixel diagonally? :)

Comment: Why not? :)) Anyway I want to find cleaner solution, because this is not only case when I need to do same